# Qtimer isActive() is returning false but it is ruining

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtimer

I am trying to use QTimer and I is starting well, but When I am trying to stop it by checking its state using isActive, it returning false always but the code inside the slot for timer is executing in correct interval.

here is code

```
void CurrentController::currentAction(void)
{
    count++;
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    if(count == 1)
    {
        qDebug()<< "Count" << count;

        QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(callMethod()));
        timer->setInterval(10000);
        timer->start();
    }
```

for stopping timer

```
    if(count >= 2)
    {
        qDebug()<< "Count2" <<timer->isActive();
        timer->stop();
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Help appreciated thanks...

Comment: Are you checking the correct timer? d->timer->isActive() vs timer->stop(). What is d?

Comment: Voting to close as this is a simple typo, and the answer won't help anyone else. Such errors happen often, since compilers can't read our minds.

Comment: sorry , I am checking correct timer ..it was by mistake I forgot to change d->timer->isActive() t0 timer->isActive()

Comment: @user1618 No, you're not. You're never remembering that newly created timer anywhere. As soon as that function/method returns, the timer is forgotten by *you*, but it still runs, and still invokes `callMethod`, only that you can't access it anymore (except as `sender()` within the body of `callMethod()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a local variable, not `d->timer`:

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
```

Yet, here you're checking if some `d->timer` is active:

```
qDebug()<< "Count2" << d->timer->isActive();
```

And a line later you refer to `timer`, not `d->timer` again:

```
timer->stop();
```

Maybe you need to decide which timer you wish to use, and stick with it :)

Comment: sorry , I am checking correct timer ..it was by mistake I forgot to change d->timer->isActive() t0 timer->isActive()

Comment: @user1618 No, you meant the other way around. As shown, your code checks a new timer each time it runs. You never store the actively running timer anywhere, you just create new timers over and over again.

Comment: Ok , it means I need to initialize it only once outside this method I guess so that the same instance will be available to stop it...Am I understood it correctly..?

Comment: @user1618 Yes. If you only need one timer, use one timer, don't create a new one all the time. Just make a `QTimer` or a `QBasicTimer` a member of your class (or the pimpl class).

Comment: @user1618 Basically, you have to understand the *meaning* of the code you write. When you write `new Foo`, that has a rather clear meaning: it gives you a fresh, new instance of `Foo`. You can't pretend that you're using the same `Foo` all the time when you, yourself, insist on getting a fresh one!

Comment: yes got it....I knew the meaning but showhow did not catch it ..thanks